# Find the range of values for k such that ${kx^2 + 3x + 9k = 0}$ has real roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, quadratics

I am asked the question:

Find the range of values for ${k}$ such that ${kx^2 + 3x + 9k = 0}$ has real roots.

So from my understanding, there are distinct roots if ${b^2 - 4ac\ge 0}$

My first step is to substitute the values into ${b^2 - 4ac}$ which gives me:

${(3)^2 - 4(k)(9k)} \ge 0$

${9 - 36k^2} \ge 0$

divided by 9 becomes

${1 - 4k^2 \ge 0}$

=> ${1 \ge 4k^2}$

=> ${{1\over4} \ge k^2}$

=> ${{1\over 2} \ge k}$

=> ${k \le {1\over2}}$

Is my answer correct or have I taken a wrong turn?

Comment: You have a typo in your original equation. I think you meant $kx^2$ instead of $k^2$.

Comment: Assuming real coefficients for a quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$, you have two distinct real roots if $b^2-4ac >0$, a double real root if $b^2-4ac = 0$, and a complex conjugate pair of roots if $b^2-4ac<0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, you should use mod ($|\ \ \ |$) as follows $$k^2\le \frac{1}{4}$$ or $$|k|\le \frac{1}{2}$$ or $$-\frac 12\le k\le \frac 12$$

Comment: I have not covered mode yet, how do I know that ${-{1\over2} < k}$,  I get why ${k < {1\over2}}$

Comment: @dagda1 My answer considers this question in your comment.

Comment: because $(-x)^2 = x^2$ and you can't assume k is positive. Consider if k = -1.  Then k <= 1/2 but -x^2 + 3x - 9 doesn't have any real solutions.  If $k^2 <= 1/4$ it follows that |k| <=1/2 from which it follows that -1/2 <= k <= 1/2.  k = -1 is not in this range (|-1| = 1 > 1/2) so if k = -1 there are no real solutions.

Answer (score 3):

$k^2\leq \frac{1}{4}$ should give you
$$-\frac{1}{2}\leq k\leq \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $k<0$ we don't have $\sqrt{k^2}=k$. If $k<0$ we have $\sqrt{k^2}=-k$. For example: for $k=-2$ we have
$$\sqrt{k^2}=\sqrt{(-2)^2}=\sqrt{4}=2=-k$$
Why? Because, by definition, the square root is always a non negative number.

Since you didn't cover modulus (absolute value) yet, you have to divide your solution in two steps: find the non negatives values of $k$ first and then find the nagatives values of $k$.

- For $k\geq 0$, we have:
  $$\vdots$$
  $$\frac{1}{4}\geq k^2$$
  $$\frac{1}{2}\geq k$$
- For $k< 0$, we have:
  $$\vdots$$
  $$\frac{1}{4}\geq k^2$$
  $$\frac{1}{2}\geq -k$$
  $$-\frac{1}{2}\leq k$$

Conclusion: $\displaystyle -\frac{1}{2}\leq k\leq \frac{1}{2}$